# ExtJS and ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am building my web UI using ExtJS and I like their MVC architecture. I was planning to do the business logic all in ASP.NET MVC as a middle layer between the UI and the database, using XML or JSON as standard data format between the two. Now, ASP.NET MVC can also generate the UI by integrating ExtJS with it. Do you think this integration is a good architectural decision, i.e. clean separation of concerns and easy to maintain/understand?

Answer (score 3):

It's probably not the answer you're looking for, but looks like there are not so many folks went to use ASP.NET + ExtJs MVC architecture. So I will tell you how we did this:

We originally planning to have web application using MS SQL Server + ASP.NET + Silverlight. But thanks god at the last moment decided to switch to ExtJs on the front end instead.

So currently we have MS SQL Server + Entity Framework + ASP.NET (somewhat MVC) + ExtJs.

I was hoping to have as much business logic as possible inside EF and ASP.NET but it turned out not to be a case. We do have some sever side filtering (whenever user doesn't have access to full set of data) in EF, as well as pretty much everything user authentication/registration related there.

However a lot of code related to tying business logic to UI got into ExtJS controllers. As well as some client end validations and some other stuff.

I would be glad to answer anything more specific if it's of any interest to you.

Comment: Thanks for your kind offer :) It seems that your ExtJS is not generated by your ASP.NET/EF layer, right? BTW, I was also planning to use Silverlight but at the last moment I decided to switch to standard HTML/JS/CSS. Why did you go that path? Is it about mobile/touch platforms?

Comment: Correct. ASP.NET just provides the data via JSON. Our decision to switch was based on the fact that SL looks to be on the downhill right now and MSFT announced that version 5 would be the last. And HTML5/JS is just rising - so looks like we will have much brighter future. And the mobile/touch platforms were very nice bonus :)